# Drupal 6 | Flexifields remove option

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I've used flexifield module to merge two of my content types. There is an option to add an item while creating a node. I want to remove rows added. I've been searching and trying to get out of this problem but found nothing. What should be done to achieve this thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set all the field value as default. It will remove extra rows and by default it will give two sets of row.